# How to eval string as go code in a go program?

Tags: go

For any go program, I'd like to turn any code as string and eval the string.

```
func main() {
    x := 10
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

For example, for the above program, I'd like to run it like the following (I am not sure what `Eval` should be). Could anybody show me what is the way to eval() go code within a go program?

```
func main() {
    x := 10
    Eval("fmt.Println(x)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not built in to the language, but you could use https://github.com/containous/yaegi

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/containous/yaegi/interp"
  "github.com/containous/yaegi/stdlib"
)

func main() {
  i := interp.New(interp.Options{})

  i.Use(stdlib.Symbols)

  _, err := i.Eval(`import "fmt"`)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  _, err = i.Eval(`fmt.Println("Hello Yaegi")`)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

but I don't think it would have access to the parent scope (so getting the value of `x` would likely be tricky)

Comment: How to get `interp` and `stdlib` installed for testing your program? Thanks.